# Cannot initialize WorkManager in direct boot mode

Tags: android-workmanager

I am new to WorkManager and I have a question about storage protection.
Tip: Cannot initialize WorkManager in direct boot mode.
I searched for a long time to find that：

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <application
     android:defaultToDeviceProtectedStorage="true"
     android:directBootAware="true">
```

My app is a boot start, so I need these two properties, but I don't know how to solve this problem, I can't find the entry that has the problem of configuring WorkManager storage.

I don't know what to do now, can't I use WorkManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update workmanager with 2.7.1 and implement ondemand initialization it should work. please remove workmanger initialization from manifest file-
provider
android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
tools:node="remove">
provider